# Wordpress Child Theme & enqueue_script

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to enqueue a script directly from my child theme's header just *after* the wp_hook, but for the life of me it's not showing up - what gives?

```
// register your script location, dependencies and version
   wp_register_script('jqtransform',
   get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/includes/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js', false);
// enqueue the script
   wp_enqueue_script('jqtransform');
```

Here's [the link](http://rockstar.tinygiantstudios.co.uk/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add enqueue_script **BEFORE** the wp_head call, as well as use a different URL path thingamabob. Here's the final code:

```
function add_my_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('jqtransform', 
    get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/includes/jqtransform/jquery.jqtransform.js', array('jquery'),'1.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('jqtransform'); 
}
add_action('init', 'add_my_scripts');
```